# Why is it that Microsoft Excel says that 8^(-1^(-8^7))) = 8 instead of 1/8?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Why is it that Microsoft Excel 7 says that 8^(-1^(-8^7))) = 8 while Wolfram Alpha says it equals 1/8?
These results are the same if I substitute -2097152.0 for -8^7.
Now -1 to any power is -1.  Therefore -1^(-8^7) = -1.  And 8^-1=1/8.
Excel is wrong.
Try it and see!

Comment: Excel 7 is 20 years old, there have been hundreds of bugs, this likely was one of them.  Stop using software from 1997.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Excel 7 (Excel 97) is from 1997, there is no possible way, for anyone to know the reason Excel 97 incorrectly calculated the specified value

Comment: @Ramhound He's also wrong in the first place. 8^((-1)^(-8^7)) is not the same as 8^(-1^(-8^7)) to Wolfram. It is to excel; in fact, Excel is more refined than Wolfram with this calculation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because `8^(-1^(-8^7)))` has mismatched parentheses and is therefore an invalid expression.

Comment: Just clarification for potential close voters: 1) A question is not off-topic because it is about old software; that just limits how many people can answer (and this problem is not limited to Excel 7). 2) A question is not necessarily off-topic because of mismatched parentheses; that might be the answer.  3) Questions that exist only because of a typo are generally considered off-topic because they aren't really about a hardware or software problem.  That appears to be the case here.  Rather than create a 3rd custom close reason, DavidPostill's reason is close enough for government work.

Comment: It turns out this has nothing to do with Excel 97. Can be replicated in Excel 20013/2016. See `=8^(-1^(-8^7))` = 8 vs `=8^(-(1^(-(8^7))))` = 0.125

Comment: @fixer1234 I've deleted my comment.

Comment: [Why does =-x^2+x for x=3 in Excel result in 12 instead of -6?](https://superuser.com/q/1385570/241386), [According to Excel, 4^3^2 = (4^3)^2. Is this really the standard mathematical convention for the order of exponentiation?](https://superuser.com/q/1386517/241386)

Answer (score 3):

Excel and Wolfram Alpha have difference precedence rules for parsing an expression like this involving exponentiation and unary minus.

```
- x ^ y
```

Excel treats unary minus as higher precedence and does it first, evaluating the expression as:

```
( - x ) ^ y
```

Wolfram Alpha does the exponentiation first, evaluating the expression as:

```
- ( x ^ y )
```

Comment: Hence Excel is a poor tool to learn the basics of math. ;).

Comment: Okay, but at least it follows the same precedence rules as C/C++.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in Excel the minus sign is used to signify both the *subtraction operator* and the *unary sign*.  It is easy to illustrate this.  In **A1** enter:

```
=-1^(ROW())
```

and copy down:

[image]

The flip/flopping positive/negative indicates that Excel sees the minus sign as a *unary* and treats this formula like:

```
=(-1)^(ROW())
```

Now in **B1** enter:

```
=0-1^(-ROW())
```

and copy down:

[image]

The lack of flip/flopping indicates that Excel sees the minus sign as a *subtraction operator* and treats this formula like:

```
=0-(1^(-ROW()))
```

Of course, the user can always control the precedence by using parenthesis.

**EDIT#1:**

See [Bill Jelen's explanation](https://books.google.com/books?id=RrvQCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT184&lpg=PT184&dq=excel%20unary%20vs%20subtraction&source=bl&ots=T3MimbZB9x&sig=cw5BErbwFoIhP7moVKWPA2M_Nz0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjc7sSepenOAhVJMyYKHUPZDMYQ6AEITDAG#v=onepage&q=excel%20unary%20vs%20subtraction&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha does this:

> -(1<sup>-2097152</sup>) = -(1) = -1
>
> 8<sup>-1</sup> = <sup>1</sup>/<sub>8</sub>

Excel, on the other hand, does this:

> (-1)<sup>-2097152</sup> = 1
>
> 8<sup>1</sup> = 8

Indeed, Excel is wrong - it should exponentiate first, then negate. Try this formula: `=8^(-(1^(-8^7)))`

> Now -1 to any power is -1

As [var firstName already pointed out](https://superuser.com/a/1118940/194694), that's incorrect. However, it's true that -1<sup>N</sup> = -1 is true for any `N` - again, because you should exponentiate first, then negate.

Comment: No, actually, Excel is right. That method of entry is incorrect. OP meant 8^((-1)^((-8)^7))

Comment: @varfirstName Why would it be incorrect? Standard [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) is: exponents and roots, then multiplication and division, then addition and subtraction. So basically the Wolfram Alpha order. Excel groups (-1) first (basically `0 - 1` subtraction), then exponentiates - that's incorrect order.

Comment: if the post-calculation multiplication was intended, it would be marked by extra separating parentheses.

Comment: @varfirstName "OP meant 8^((-1)^((-8)^7))". You don't know that. It's not what he wrote (in two different places).

Comment: @gronostaj I think more properly stated is that Excel ranks **negation** first (unary minus), and then `exponentiation`, then `multiplication and division`, then `addition and subtraction`.  In Excel, `-1` is different from `0-1`.  eg:  `-1^2` ► `1`.  `0-1^2` ► `-1`.  The first is considered a unary operator, the second a binary operator.

Answer (score 0):

That's incorrect. -1^2 is 1. However, -1 to any odd power is -1; that is true. Using perfectly sensible logic, you can say that 8^(-1^(-8^7)). -8 ^ 7 = -2,097,152, an even number; therefore, -1^(-2,097,152) is 1/(-1^(2,097,152)) which reduces to 1/1 or simply *1*, and 8^1 is 8. Your entry to WolframAlpha is flawed in some way.

EDIT: I did the calculation on Wolfram and it turns out that you entered it wrong. You're supposed to isolate the -1 further from the base, like this:

```
8^( (-1)^(-8^7) )
```

Wolfram spit this out back at me (identical to my entry):

```
8^((-1)^(-8^7))
```

Comment: He says that -1 to *any* power is -1 which is completely incorrect.

Comment: No, that's completely incorrect, any number to the -1 is 1 over that number

Comment: My point is, he said *negative one* to **_any_** power is -1, which is incorrect. (negative one being the base, in all circumstances.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44656/discussion-between-var-firstname-and-ramhound).

Comment: This is wrong. In math power operator has higher precedence than unary minus so [-1^2 = -1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Unary_minus_sign), and it has right-to-left associativity so [2^3^4 = 2^(3^4)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Serial_exponentiation). Almost all languages with power operator do follow the math rule like that. See [Why is exponentiation applied right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47429513/995714), [Why is exponentiation right associative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1673740/90333)